# Second minipage extends past right margin

Tags: pdftex

I am trying divide the page using 2 minipages that take up 50% of the `\textwidth` each. However, the second minipage extends past the right margin of the page. At first, I thought this was some `\renewcommand` or some package setting that I set and forgot about. So, I created a completely new document with only the code below, and still, I have this issue. I have googled this extensively, but the solutions I see are all related to `\noindent`, `%` after the first minipage, or some other spacing tweak that I either already do, or don't fix anything.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}    % Set margin width

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\noindent
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    TEXT 1
\end{minipage}}% This must go next to `\end{minipage}`
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    TEXT 2
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot of the issue:
[image]

Thanks in advanced.
Sam

Comment: Welcome. Regarding your MWE you already got the answer by @UlrikeFischer. But its not totally clear from your question, if you need the `fbox` to wrap the `minipages` or if you just used them to visualise your problem. If the latter is the case, just remove the `fboxes` from your code and it will work without further changes.

Answer (score 3):

You must take the spaces from the fbox into account:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in,showframe]{geometry}    % showframe to see the margin

\begin{document}
 \begin{center}
  %noindent is not needed in center.
        \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimeval{0.5\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}}
            TEXT 1
        \end{minipage}}% This must go next to `\end{minipage}`
        \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimeval{0.5\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}}
            TEXT 2
    \end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `fbox` also consumes some space. You could use a `framebox` instead. Then, the following code should solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}    % Set margin width

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \noindent%
        \framebox[0.5\textwidth]{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            TEXT 1
        \end{minipage}}% This must go next to `\end{minipage}`
        \framebox[0.5\textwidth]{\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
            TEXT 2
    \end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this gives bad inner margins, the inner boxes are too large and stick out of the frame box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` parameters. In the code below, I back up by `\fboxrule`, so you don't get two adjacent rules in the middle.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent x\hfill x% this is to show the margins

\noindent
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimeval{.5\textwidth-2\fboxsep-1.5\fboxrule}}
  \lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{minipage}}% This must go next to `\end{minipage}`
\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimeval{.5\textwidth-2\fboxsep-1.5\fboxrule}}
  \lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want that the two boxes have the same height, you can use `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent x\hfill x% this is to show the margins

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
  \lipsum[1][1-4] &
  \lipsum[2][1-3] \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]